# Let me know about sound-producing flatus

Tags: word-request

I want to know that the flatus which produce sound is said to be _______.

In other words, when someone farts but produce sound with it, that action is said to be (a) ______?

Comment: Perhaps you mean ftatulence, in common English, a fart.

Comment: @Lambie ftatulence -> flatulence

Comment: Worth noting that in my experience "flatulence" is a common enough slightly clinical phrase for gas / a fart, but "flatus" looks like an obscure medical term that I would expect to be almost totally unknown -- I had never heard of it before this question.

Answer (score 1):

One term is [*trump*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trump) (BrE, possibly dated). This directly replaces *fart* as a verb, but it also means the sound that is made. A trumpeter makes the same sound (with the lips) when playing a trumpet.

> **trump** verb [NO OBJECT] informal
>
> Break wind audibly.
>
> **trump** noun (archaic)
>
> A trumpet or a trumpet blast.

Oxford Dictionaries

Comment: I dunno about this one - I don't think ever once in my life have I (northeastern US English native speaker) heard this used.

Comment: @stangdon Any British ex-schoolboy (of a certain age) will be familiar with it. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Fair enough!  I'll amend my comment to point out where it is that I haven't heard it.

Comment: @stangdon This has caused a great deal of hilarity in the UK with regards to the current POTUS-elect.

Comment: a trumpeting sound.